# issue in integration of google analytics in ios static library

Tags: iphone

Hey  i want to integrate google analytics in my ios  static library, but when i'm putting `libGoogleAnalytics.a` from `google analytics sdk` for ios  in my own static library i'm getting this error

```
Libtool build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libHY5Lib.a normal i386
    cd /Hy5Canvas/Lib/HY5Lib
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Hy5Canvas/Lib/HY5Lib/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Hy5Canvas/Lib/HY5Lib/HY5Lib -L/Hy5Canvas/Lib/HY5Lib -filelist /Hy5Canvas/Lib/HY5Lib/build/HY5Lib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HY5Lib.build/Objects-normal/i386/HY5Lib.LinkFileList -ObjC -framework Foundation -lGoogleAnalytics -o /Hy5Canvas/Lib/HY5Lib/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libHY5Lib.a
```

**Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1**

Kindly help me out on this issue
Thanks,

Comment: Don't you have a more specific error message? "failed with exit code 1" doesn't really tell anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics SDK for iOS isn't built for the armv7s architecture. This architecture just became available in Xcode 4.5 (released 9/12/2012), and is required for building for the new iPhone 5. Please release a new version of the SDK that includes this architecture.

Refer : [Google Analytics Issue](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=232)

Hope this helps :)